# JPA OneToMany The Many With same model and same column

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

**Article.java**

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "refId", referencedColumnName = "id")
private List<Attachment> attachmentList;
```

**Book.java**

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "refId", referencedColumnName = "id")
private List<Attachment> attachmentList;
```

**Attachment.java**

```
private String refId
```

The Article and Book has many Attachment and join with same column "refId".
The Attachment Entity how to code?

Comment: [Read](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Just create simple Address entity and that's it - it works if you want one-directional relation. And as I understand your Order is an Abstract class with some inheritance stategy where you have CardOrder and FoodOrder ref with Address Reference which will be only to get/set address for your children : FoodOrder and CarOrder;

Comment: Thank you for reply.If I do above code,it prompt `Caused by:  org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: xxx.xxx.xxx.Attachment column: ref_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to me: How can I know, by looking at an Attachment record, whether it is a Book or an Article that the refId column is referring to?  You should have separate columns to store relationship of Attachment to Book and Article.

If Book and Article are sharing the key, that implies Book and Article should share a parent class, then it should look something like:

```
class Document {
    @Id
    Long id;

    @OneToMany
    List<Attachment> attachments;
}

class Article extends Document {
    //....
}

class Book extends Document {
    //....
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.If I do this code, It can't create relationship key, and then save Article can't save Attachment List, and save Attachment must manually.
`articleDao.save(entity);attachmentDao.save(entity.getAttachments())`.how can only do articleDao.save(entity);

Comment: that's another question: look on topic about cascading insert/update/delete